# Iterate through JSON Response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, loops, responsetext

this is the response string I am trying to iterate through:

```
{
"page": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/8uO0gUM8aNqYLs1OsTBQiXu0fEv.jpg",
        "id": 550,
        "original_title": "Fight Club",
        "release_date": "1999-10-15",
        "poster_path": "/2lECpi35Hnbpa4y46JX0aY3AWTy.jpg",
        "popularity": 61151.745000000003,
        "title": "Fight Club",
        "vote_average": 9.0999999999999996,
        "vote_count": 174
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/5Z0FScA1bB6EbdGmZCUBeUk32eV.jpg",
        "id": 14476,
        "original_title": "Clubbed",
        "release_date": "2008-10-02",
        "poster_path": "/bl6PEQtmohEP1zP9srNZY6bXyHg.jpg",
        "popularity": 1.7290000000000001,
        "title": "Clubbed",
        "vote_average": 7.7999999999999998,
        "vote_count": 3
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/qw2Qb42xtyE1B449JoTgb1mVCe1.jpg",
        "id": 51021,
        "original_title": "Lure: Teen Fight Club",
        "release_date": "2010-11-16",
        "poster_path": "/aRTX5Y52yGbVL6TGnyI4E8jjtz4.jpg",
        "popularity": 0.26600000000000001,
        "title": "Lure: Teen Fight Club",
        "vote_average": 0.0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": "/tcoAGvTo96R7Y9ZGVCCz7BZvrvb.jpg",
        "id": 104782,
        "original_title": "Florence Fight Club",
        "release_date": "2010-01-01",
        "poster_path": "/eQqqu0srTYcclWqylvgpLyU87hV.jpg",
        "popularity": 0.085000000000000006,
        "title": "Florence Fight Club",
        "vote_average": 0.0,
        "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
        "adult": false,
        "backdrop_path": null,
        "id": 115584,
        "original_title": "Fight Club – The “I am Jack’s Laryngitis” Edit",
        "release_date": null,
        "poster_path": null,
        "popularity": 0.059999999999999998,
        "title": "Fight Club – The “I am Jack’s Laryngitis” Edit",
        "vote_average": 0.0,
        "vote_count": 0
    }
],
"total_pages": 1,
"total_results": 5
}
```

I want to iterate through the results and pull some attribues such as original_title, release_date, etc. I tried using the below code (among others) to try printing one line to no avail:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
alert(data.page[0].results[0].original_title);
```

Comment: You don't need `page`. Just `console.log(data.results[0])` will work.

Comment: In addition to what @JulianH.Lam said, page is not an array. It's an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `page` attribute is not part of the intended result set you want to retrieve. Try this:

```
alert(data.results[0].original_title);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know it was such a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.page[0]`:

```
alert(data.results[0].original_title);
```